# MATLAB - how to construct all possible binary vectors {+1, -1} for 10 entries?

Tags: matlab, loops, vector

I'm looking to create all possible binary combinations, in vectors of length 10, of values +1 and -1. Only two possible values, e.g.

```
x = [1 1 1 -1 1 -1 -1 1 -1 1]
```

...is one such combination. There are 2^10 == 1024 possible vectors of this format. Is there a nifty way of coming up with all of them (perhaps in a matrix of size 10x1024) with a few lines?

My application needs to test all input combinations of this type in a function. Right now the only solution I can think of is to construct 10 nested for-loops and in the very inside test `x[a b c d e f g h i j]` where the 10 characters iterate between +1 and -1. I'd rather not do that and learn something cool if possible. Cheers.

Comment: I'd iterate from 1 to 1024, convert to binary, explode it and replace 0 with -1 each time

Comment: Cartesian product of `Vs{:}` defined by: `Vs = repmat({[-1,1]},10,1)`